# React Search filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically what my code does is display a table list of names with a search bar at the top that filters the list as you type in a value.
The problem I am having with my code at the moment is adding an if statement to the DisplayTable component. I dont want it to display all the stored data but just display the ones that have been inputted by the user in the search bar {queryText}

Please Ignore the tableData variable

```
var InstantBox = React.createClass({
    doSearch:function(queryText){
        console.log(queryText)
        //get query result
        var queryResult=[];
        this.props.data.forEach(function(person){
            if(person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
            queryResult.push(person);
        });

        this.setState({
            query:queryText,
            filteredData: queryResult
        })
    },
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            query:'',
            filteredData: this.props.data
        }
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="InstantBox">
                <h2>Who is Richer?</h2>
                <SearchBox query={this.state.query} doSearch={this.doSearch}/>
                <DisplayTable data={this.state.filteredData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var SearchBox = React.createClass({
    doSearch:function(){
        var query=this.refs.searchInput.getDOMNode().value; // this is the search text
        this.props.doSearch(query);
    },
    render:function(){
        return <input className="searchbar-edit" type="text" ref="searchInput" placeholder="Search Name" value={this.props.query} onChange={this.doSearch}/>
    }
});

var DisplayTable = React.createClass({
      doSearch:function(queryText){
        console.log(queryText)
        //get query result
        var queryResult=[];
        this.props.data.forEach(function(person){
            if(person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
            queryResult.push(person);
        });

        this.setState({
            query:queryText,
            filteredData: queryResult
        })
    },

    render:function(){
        //making the rows to display
        var rows=[];
        this.props.data.forEach(function(person) {
        rows.push(<tr><td>{person.image}</td></tr>)
        rows.push(<tr><td>{person.name}</td></tr>)
        });        
        //returning the table
        return(
             <table>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});

var tableData=[
{
    name:'Paul mak',
    image: <img width="50" src="./images/profile_img.png"/>,
},
];

var dataSource=[
{
    name:'Paul mak',
    image: <img width="50" src="./images/profile_img.png"/>,
},
{
    name:'John Doe',
    image : '002'
},
{
    name:'Sachin Tendulkar',
    image : '003'
}];


React.render(
  <InstantBox data={dataSource}/>,
  document.getElementById('content1')
);
```

Comment: Tagging all the frameworks know to mankind is frowned upon, which one are you using?

Comment: sorry about that.. react.js

Comment: Are you wanting for it to simply hide the data from the page (more css'y), or not even render it (react)?

Comment: You can find the tutorial on building search filter here https://youtu.be/RM_nXOyHwN0

Comment: you could use this https://github.com/kevalbhatt/react-structured-query-search

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var InstantBox = React.createClass({
    doSearch:function(queryText){
        console.log(queryText)
        //get query result
        var queryResult=[];
        this.props.data.forEach(function(person){
            if(person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
            queryResult.push(person);
        });

        this.setState({
            query:queryText,
            filteredData: queryResult
        })
    },
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            query:          '',
            filteredData:   undefined
        }
    },

    renderResults: function() {
        if (this.state.filteredData) {
            return (
                <DisplayTable data={this.state.filteredData}/>
            );
        }
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="InstantBox">
                <h2>Who is Richer?</h2>
                <SearchBox query={this.state.query} doSearch={this.doSearch}/>
                {this.renderResults()}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

What I've changed from your code is I changed `this.state.filteredData` to be undefined (in fact you could just remove it entirely, but I thought this was clearer for you right now) in your initial state.  This way when you first render the box, there's no `filteredData` and your `<DisplayTable />` doesn't render.  As soon as you run your `doSearch` callback from `<SearchBox />` it will populate `filteredData` and display it.

To extend this you could also check when `this.state.query` is undefined again or blank (eg with : `this.state.query.length`) to remove `<DisplayTable />` from the dom again if there is no query / no results.

Remember `render` functions are still just javascript.  Anything you wrap in `{}` inside JSX will be evaluated.  We could have just had this logic inside the `render` function and be doing something like `var displayTable = <DisplayTable />;` and then including `{displayTable}` in the returned JSX and it would have been the same.  I personally just prefer splitting render logic up among different functions :)